# Postfix not receiving email from gmail but it does recieve from hotmail

Tags: postfix, gmail

I got Zentyal SOGo installed. I can send emails from SOGo and both the gmail and hotmail accounts receive the emails.

I reply the email from hotmail and SOGo receives the email.
I reply the email from gmail and the email does not arrives.

Any Ideas? Where should i look? Any documentation recommended to read?

Comment: Have you looked at the spam folder yet?

Comment: Yes and no there are no emails on the spam folder